# objective c compare range intersect

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to find the intersection of 2 number ranges, say for example...

range A is from 10 to 100,
range B is from 60 to 70

Is there an easy way without writing a load of if statements to calculate the intersection of the two ranges, so in this example it would be 10.

Thanks,

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If you have or make `NSRange` objects, the [NSIntersectionRange](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/1413065-nsintersectionrange?language=occ) function will do this for you.  Just be sure to check what it returns when there is no intersection.

```
NSRange a = NSMakeRange(10, 90);
NSRange b = NSMakeRange(60, 10);
NSRange intersection = NSIntersectionRange(a, b);
if (intersection.length <= 0)
    NSLog(@"Ranges do not intersect");
else
    NSLog(@"Intersection = %@", NSStringFromRange(intersection));
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm looking for `NSIntersectionRange` method :D

Comment: `NSIntersectionRange` is a broken link

Answer (score 3):

You can use this method for that purpose:

```
NSRange NSIntersectionRange (
   NSRange range1,
   NSRange range2
);
```

You can find all the info here:

[NSIntersectionRange Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/1413065-nsintersectionrange?language=occ)