# Check if one NSRange is within another NSRange or interSecting with it in swift ?

Tags: swift, nsrange

if
case 1 :  range1 is (5,10) and range2 is (8,0) it should return true.
case 2 : range1 is (5,10) and range2 is (5,4) it should return true.
case 3 if range1 is (5,10) and range2 is (14,20) it should return true.
How to implement a function that return true for all cases. 
I want to check if a range intersect with another range or completely within it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10172688/objective-c-compare-range-intersect ? Shouldn't be big difficulties to adapt from Objective-C to Swift

Comment: `NSRange(8,0)` is an *empty* range, it does not overlap with anything.

Comment: But this range falls within Range (5,10). I want to check falls condition as well.

Comment: NSRange(8, 0) is the same as NSRange(30, 0) , so you cannot say that one of them intersects with (5,10)

Comment: @Gerriet No, those two ranges are not equal. They have the same length but not the same start. But `8,0` definitely intersects `(5,10)`.

Comment: @rmaddy: I see that differently. `NSRange(location: 8, length: 0)` describes the integers `x` satisfying `8 <= x < 8 + 0`, i.e. an empty range. `NSRange(location: 8, length: 0)` and `NSRange(location: 5, length: 10)` have no common elements.

Comment: @MartinR I was thinking of it like an axis on a graph. I shouldn't have these discussions first thing in the morning (for me). I was thinking that the location `8` is within the range `5-15` and that the length of `0` was irrelevant. But I guess most uses of `NSRange` aren't used that way.

Comment: Thank you @MartinR . You got my point.

Answer (score 9):

Range (the Swift way) has a method overlaps. 
If you want to work with NSRange it would be:

```
NSIntersectionRange(range1, range2).length > 0
```

Comment: but I have two NSRange object.

Comment: Edited my answer to include the NSRange-version.